# bison LAC (Lookahead Correction) example

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I saw [LAC](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/LAC.html) but still I can't find any good example or tutorial 
 on how to improve syntax errors handling using this mechanism (or any similar way)
any help would be appreciated